# Rq custom close reason "literal description" for riddles

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, discussion

To borrow Emrakul's wording explaining a down vote:

"it takes literal aspects of an object and describes them directly, and shows minimal effort to create a well-developed puzzle."

Answer (score 1):

We currently do not have enough agreement on [the meta question about this](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5160/what-should-we-do-about-riddles-that-are-pure-trivia)  to start to close questions for this reason.

If the answer suggesting closing has a high enough score, we will start to close questions for that reason. If enough questions need to be closed for that reason, we will get a custom close reason.

Comment: (That being said, I'm *all for* a close reason - we need to actually have a rationale behind wanting it though, and first that requires it to be closeworthy.)

Comment: I'm the only person who posted an answer arguing against it and I've done a U-turn. ;P

Comment: @AE: True! But we should *probably* wait until the "close" answer has garnered more upvotes.

Comment: Yours is the top-voted answer (now)! ;)

Comment: @AE Please don't delete answers on meta just because you no longer agree with what you said there. The voting on such answers is still an important reflector of community consensus, regardless of your personal opinion.